# Is it possible to use a different font with HieroTex?

Tags: fonts

For typesetting Egyptian hieroglyphs, I've found the old package HieroTex (aka Sesh Nesout) to be extremely useful. Most of the time, its automatic arrangement of signs works well enough (even if it's not perfect) to make me prefer it to manual arrangement with TikZ.

However, the default font doesn't scale well to large sizes, and the documentation is…somewhat lacking. As far as I can tell, it *seems* that it's designed to work with custom fonts, using `\declareHieroGlyphicFont`. I'd like to use this to swap in something prettier, like Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs. But I can't figure out how to actually make it work.

Is it possible, without too much hacking, to use a separate TTF font with HieroTex, instead of the default T1 one?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{hiero}
\usepackage{egypto}

\begin{document}

\begin{hieroglyph}
D:d-i-n:f x:r zA-A1:f
\end{hieroglyph}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How important is it to stay backward-compatible with the exact syntax of `hierotex`?

Comment: @Davislor Not at all. If there's another way of laying out hieroglyphs (in a font of my choice) that lets me use quadrats without manually specifying every position in TikZ, that would also be wonderful. I just figured focusing on the framework of HieroTex would keep this question narrow enough to be answerable.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [Aegyptus from the Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts site.](https://dn-works.com/ufas/)  This font contains several hundred OpenType ligatures for many heiroglyphs, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\egyptianfont{Aegyptus}[
  BoldFont = *Bold ,
  Ligatures = Common ,
  Scale = MatchUppercase ,
  Extension = .otf ]

\newcommand\zwnj{^^^^200c}

\begin{document}
\bfseries
{\egyptianfont ^^^^^^013193^^^^^^013191^^^^^^013216^^^^^^0130bb }
{\egyptianfont ^^^^^^013193^^^^^^013191{\zwnj}^^^^^^013216^^^^^^0130bb}
\end{document}
```

[image: Aegyptus font sample]

The font also supports the Hierotic, Heiroglyphic and Transliteration alphabets through stylistic sets, and some stylistic alternatives.

Unfortunately, the latest version with all these great features is *gratis* for personal use only.  You should contact the designer to ask about licensing it otherwise, or your institution to see if it already has.

The [last version of Aegyptus that was released “free for any use” was 6.17.](https://web.archive.org/web/20180212144935/http://users.teilar.gr:80/%7Eg1951d/) (From the Internet Archive.)  That page also has a companion font, in a custom encoding, called Abydos.

Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs is a possible substitute that covers the Unicode glyphs, but does not support any ligatures.  Since you ask, here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\egyptianfont{NotoSansEgyptianHieroglyphs}[
  UprightFont = *-Regular ,
  Scale = MatchUppercase ,
  Extension = .ttf ]

\begin{document}
{\egyptianfont ^^^^^^013362^^^^^^013362^^^^^^013362^^^^^^013362^^^^^^013362}
{\egyptianfont ^^^^^^013366}
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs sample]

It would be possible to map Gardner codes, or some other codes, to Unicode codepoints, for instance using Lua, a `.tec` `Mapping=` in XeTeX, or regular-expression search-and-replace, but I have not attempted to do so.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, while Aegyptus does have a lot of quadrats built in, it doesn't seem to have any ability to let me compose my own; the main reason I'm still using HieroTex is because it lets me specify my own layout.