# How to add this package (HieroTeX) to Overleaf and/or MiKTeX?

Tags: packages, miktex, overleaf

So, basically, its instructions seems to be a little outdated, and, even when I follow step by step the instructions I find on-line, nothing works at all. Can someone explain to me how to add this package as if I were a mentally handicapped individual? (Because I am indeed in regards to LaTeX.) I want to transcribe Gardiner’s Middle Egyptian grammar, all of it, on LaTeX. Any help is welcome. (“hieroglf” doesn’t seem to be enough to what I want to do, nor it looks intuitive.)

• https://github.com/hierotex/hierotex

• https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hieroglyph

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546542/2388

Comment: you might find it easier these days to use a Unicode font and lualatex eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575606/1090

Comment: I tried and couldn't - legacy fonts appear to be broken (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/installing-hieroglyph-package/650052#650052). Unicode ttf/otf fonts and lualatex is much easier (same link).

Comment: Yes, it's a bit confusing and outdated description. Perhaps the best way is to google the author and contact him. At least within the last 12 months he published. (Perhaps he's even listed here?) Perhaps somtehing better might be available for you today? // What's about David's hint? // Did you see these links? https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=hierotex

Comment: May be see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/451530/hierotex-by-serge-rosmorduc-manual-installation ... and the link mentioned inside: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/installing-hieroglyph-package .

Answer (score 1):

At least some partial hints, unless you found out yourself already.

**1. Download**

On Github download the zip file, run a virus check on the download and open it in a file explorer (WIndows).

[image]

**2. Directories**

In the .zip file find the folders mentioned in the installation section of the manual (pdf, on the git-page) here:

[image: source]
[image: latex]

Looks like you need to compile sesh to obtain an executeable:

[image: sesh]

On Windows the MikTex installion seems to be at:

*C:\users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTex*

**3. Updating via the MikTex console:**

As mentioned in [Installing Hieroglyph Package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377937/installing-hieroglyph-package) , find the relevant menues here:

[image: updating console]

**4. Using HieroTex:**

As mentioned in the previous link, HieroTex seems to run from the commandline:

[image: command line]